# Direct Comparison Test question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n} + 7^{n}}{3^{n} + 8^{n}}$ converges or diverges.

I'm not sure if this is the correct method. I can apply Bernoulli's inequality to each term e.g. $3^{n} = (1+2)^{n} > 1 + 2n$. Doing this for each term I get

$\frac{3^{n} + 7^{n}}{3^{n}+8^{n}} > \frac{(1+2n)+(1+6n)}{(1+2n)+(1+7n)}$ then since the constants don't really matter this is like $\frac{8}{9}$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Another thought I had, was to try and write the series or compare it to a geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n} + 7^{n}}{3^{n} + 8^{n}}\leq 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{7^{n}}{8^{n}}=14$

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $3^n+7^n>(1+2n)+(1+6n)$ for all $n\ge 2$, and that $3^n+8^n>(1+2n)+(1+7n)$ for all $n\ge 2$. But you certainly can't conclude from this that $$\frac{3^{n} + 7^{n}}{3^{n}+8^{n}} > \frac{(1+2n)+(1+6n)}{(1+2n)+(1+7n)}$$ for all $n\ge 2$!

The same logic would assert that $\frac38 > \frac12$ because $3>1$ and $8>2$.

Comment: Yeah this is why I shouldn't try and do mathematics at 3:00AM -.- thanks.